# How to access/edit information about included audio files?

Tags: game-engine

I have a blend file that is supposed to be packed with a few wav audio files, but it seems the author forgot to pack them, and I don't have the files, if I try the option **File>External Data>Pack into blend file** blender shows the error:

***Unable to pack file, source path '//long path/something.wav' not found***

I've found the library where those files were originally downloaded, and downloaded the required files, now I want to edit the information in the blend file so that blender can find those files.

Comment: have you tried recreating the directory structure that Blender is looking for?  You have one of them listed in your question.  I'm guessing that the folder "long path" should be next to the .blend

Comment: Yes, I ended up re-creating all the directory structure, it seems there is no way to edit those paths directly in blender.

Comment: Once you have re-created the directories and blender finds the files you could pack external data so you won't need the external copies any more?

Comment: @sambler ok, I did that too, also used the option to convert all paths to relative paths, to remove any sensitive data , but I don't know what that option really does.

Comment: Paths are either relative or absolute - relative is directions from the blendfile to the data file. Absolute is an exact location on disk. A new question can expand that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the file path of the Sound Datablock (and any external file) using the Outliner:

[image]

1. From the header, make sure the outliner is set to display '**Datablocks**'.
2. Browser to the **Sounds** section and find the sound datablock you want to edit.
3. Expand the RNA and modify the **File Path** string as required.
4. You might have to restart Blender to force a reload.